# equation for a general monotonic function

Tags: math

I am trying to define a general monotonic function where linear is a special case of non-linear for certain parameter values and which can be increasing or decreasing. I think it should be possible but I cannot write it out. The non-linear curve need not have the exact shape as shown in the figure, I just need something non-linear.

Characteristics:
x between -10 and 10
y between 5 and 0.2
monotonic: increasing, decreasing, linear, non-linear

I faked a plot to show what I am looking for.
thanks

[general montonic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzvv5.png)

Comment: Do you want the curves to be symmetric wrt the lines ?

Comment: no, the non-linear curve need not be symmetrical in the way I have depicted them in the plot but I would like to have it somewhat gradual rather than strongly exponential.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

`x^α` and `1 - (1 - x)^α` have the desired behavior (try `α < 1` and `α > 1`). This holds for `x` in `[0, 1]`. Rescale as needed.

Answer (score 0):

For each `a > 0`, the function `f_a` defined by

```
f_a(x) = 4.8((x+10)/20)^a + 0.2
```

is a monotonic increasing function on the interval `[-10,10]` passing through `(-10,0.2)` and `(10,5)`. `f_1` is your linear function.

The class of functions `g_a` defined by:

```
g_a(x) = -4.8((x+10)/20)^a + 5
```

are monotonic decreasing functions on `[-10,10]` passing through `(-10,5)` and `(10,0.2)`.